# Prove that Yn converge in law to uniform(-1,1)

Tags: statistics

For $Y \sim$  Uniform$(-1,1)$
$ Y_{n}=  \begin{cases}
 \text{Y if } \vert Y \vert  \leq 1-\frac{1}{n}\\
 \text{n if } \vert Y \vert >1-\frac{1}{n}\\
 \end{cases}   $

Prove   $Y_{n}\xrightarrow{L}Y$

---

Let $Y_n=Y$ if $|Y| <= 1-1/n$, or n if $|Y| > 1-1/n$, where $Y~$uniform$(-1,1)$
Prove that $Y_n$ converge in law to Y.

I tried:
CDFs: $F_{Y_n} = P(Y <= y) = (y+2)/n$ if $|Y| <= 1-1/n$;

or

$F_{Y_n} = P(Yn <= n) = P(n <= x) = 1$ if $n < x; 0$ if $n > x$

Let $H_n(y) = F_{Y_n}$, $H(y) = $CDF of $Y$ which is uniform(-1,1)
Since $H_n(y) -> H(y)$
So, the distribution functions Hn converge weakly to H by the definition of converge in law
Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you use Latex to edit your question as it is supposed to be on this website? Thanks!

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for helping me fix the format issue!